# Traversing a dictionary in a python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to traverse a dictionary present in rows of my python Dataframe.See one row of the Dataframe below for reference:
State column is empty.

Unnamed: 0    City    State   Country     PostalCode          Distance
720  4976     Barcelona         Spain        08001             {'08001': 0, '08002': 2.2, '08003': 2.2}

When I am running the below code this error is coming up-> TypeError: string indices must be integers

CODE:

```
import sys
import json
import pandas as pd
dfglobal=pd.read_csv("postcoderadius.csv")
#print(dfglobal)
filtered_df2  = pd.DataFrame([])
# s=sys.argv[1]
# ci=s[s.find("City=")+5:s.find("&State")]
# cs=s[s.find('State')+6:s.find("&Country")]
# ci=ci.replace('+','')
# cs=cs.replace('+','-')
# co=s[s.find("Country")+8:s.find("&ZipCode")]
# givenpostal=s[s.find("ZipCode")+8:s.find("&Radius")]
# radius=float(s[s.find("Radius")+8:])
ci="Barcelona"
co="Spain"
cs=""
givenpostal="08001"
radius=4.0
print(ci,co,cs,givenpostal,radius)
#print("hello1")
filtered_df2=pd.concat([filtered_df2,dfglobal[(dfglobal['Country'] == co) & (dfglobal['City'] == ci) &  (dfglobal['PostalCode'] == givenpostal)]])
#print(filtered_df2)
#filtered_df2['PostalCode']=filtered_df2['PostalCode'].apply(str)
a_dict=filtered_df2['Distance']
#print(a_dict)
result  = pd.DataFrame([])
resp=[]
resr=[]
for index, row in filtered_df2.iterrows():
    #print(row['Distance'])
    dictp=row['Distance']
    for key in dictp: 
        print(dictp[key])


result['PostalCode']=resp
result['City']=ci
result['Country']=co
result['Radius']=resr
result=result.reindex(["City","Country","PostalCode","Radius"],axis=1)
result.to_csv("distance.csv")
```

Comment: Can you post more sample data so I can perform some tests and further investigate? Also, is *Unnamed* a column?

Comment: Yes unamed:0 is a column

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that `row['Distance']` doesn't return a dictionary,
but a string. (if it doesn't, please give a full, reproducable example)

So after `dictp = row['Distance']` `dictp` is a string.

`for key in dictp` will return each letter of the string.

`print(dictp[key])` will then cause the error, because for strings,
`key` needs to be a number.

You can check if this is your problem by printing `type(dictp)` after the `dictp=row['Distance']` line. If this prints `str` then that's the reason.

Here's how you can fix this:

You can convert a string to a real dictionary using the `eval()`function.

Like this:

```
dictp = "{'08001': 0, '08002': 2.2, '08003': 2.2}"
mydict = eval(dictp)
```

Please note that this is a security risk if you can't guarantee that there really is a dict for all lines, because it runs the code.